# Avoid repeated codes in Javascript: many buttons for playing audios

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

*Here is an easy situation:*
    There are 26 buttons for 26 alphabetic letters. If one click the button, the audio of the corresponding letters will be played once. How to make codes as concise as possible?

*Here is what I want to do:*
    I plan to build a website for learning languages. Here is the button I need to create:

1. When the mouse enters the button (originally white) area (mouseenter()), the button will turn blue and play the audio repeatedly;
2. If the mouse leaves the button area (mouseleave()), the button will turn white back and pause playing the audio.
3. I might have many many buttons or similar UI components.

   How to design to make the codes as concise and reusable as possible?

*I have realized the animation of one button, please see the codes below. But I find it awkward to write each button the very similar piece of code. Please help me abstract codes under such a situation.*

```
<audio loop src="audio/alphabet/n.mp3" id="alphabetpronunciationn"></audio>
<button id="buttonalphabetn" class="btn btn-default btn-block">N n</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var audioalphabetn = document.getElementById("alphabetpronunciationn");
    $("#buttonalphabetn").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#buttonalphabetn").addClass("btn-primary");
    audioalphabetn.play();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $("#buttonalphabetn").removeClass("btn-primary");
    audioalphabetn.pause();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Now I know to abstract the animation of changing color into a customized class. But how to simplify the codes of playing audios for each button?

Comment: Why are you mixing vanilla JS selector and jQuery's selector mechanism?

Comment: I am not very familiar with JS selector and jQuery. That's the reason why I cannot handle them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Build a `letter -> audio element` map, so that you can easily reference an audio element given the letter it corresponds to. e.g.

```
var audios = {};
'abc...xyz'.split('').forEach(function(letter) {
   audios[letter] = document.getElementById('alphabetpronunciation' + letter);
});
```

Add a `data-*` attribute to each button, containing the letter it represents and give each button the same class instead of individual IDs:

```
<button data-letter="n" class="letter btn btn-default btn-block">N n</button>
```

Use that class to bind the event handler to all buttons. The event handler gets their `data-letter` attribute and accesses the map:

```
$("button.letter").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
    audios[$(this).data('letter')].play();
});
```

I highlight recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/), especially about [selectors](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) and [events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is pretty neat. But I still have questions: 1.audios is an array (e.g., `27 - > [object HTMLAudioElement]`). The mapping part is correct, however, if I want to get the specific data, I need to find the right index **number**, instead of the specific **letter**. In other words, there is no **key** in audio like a **map**. This will become a problem if there is no clear sequence among the data. How to fetch the object in the map with a **letter key**?

Comment: 2. It is still a mix of DOM and jQuery, which is not recommended. Is there any way to "purify" the code style?

Comment: Duh, of course, fixed the mapping. *"Is there any way to "purify" the code style?"* Just replace `document.getElementById(...)` with jQuery? I'm sure you know how to look for an element by ID with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
    $('.btn-audio').on('mouseenter',function() {
        // add class to button, find previous sibling, start play
        $(this).addClass("btn-primary").prev().play();
    }).on('mouseleave',function() {
        // and reversve...
        $(this).removeClass("btn-primary").prev().pause();
    });
 });
```

In case this is your real html. In case the tags are differently nested you might need another selector than prev or maybe an data-attribute for the button containing the id of the corresponding audio file.

```
<audio loop src="audio/alphabet/n.mp3" id="alphabetpronunciationn"></audio>
<button id="buttonalphabetn" class="btn btn-audio btn-default btn-block">N n</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to each button to indicate the letter that it represents.  In this example I'll use a data attribute called "playLetter".

`<Button id="SomeButtonA" data-playLetter="A">Play A</Button>
 <Button id="SomeButtonB" data-playLetter="B">Play B</Button>
 <Button id="SomeButtonC" data-playLetter="C">Play C</Button>`

Select all of the buttons that have the playLetter attribute and assign handlers.  This means the same handler will be called for each and every button.  Within the handler, use `$(this).data("playLetter")` to read the data attribute and determine which letter to play for the specific button.

```
$(":Button[data-playLetter]").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
    audioalphabet.play($(this).data("playLetter");
    });

$(":Button[data-playLetter]").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("btn-primary");
    audioalphabet.pause();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution. Your way of thinking blows my mind. However, I did get all the details. What is 'audioalphabet' here? Why $(this).data("playLetter") can read data? What is the data() ? Where can I find related fields on this?

Comment: I looked up online for data-attribute of javascript and now I understand everything. Your design is very concise! Thanks for you answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I myself come up with a solution. Here is what I did:

```
<button id="buttonalphabetü" 
  class="btn btn-default btn-block buttonchangingcolorblue" 
  onmouseenter="play('alphabetpronunciationn')"
  onmouseleave="pause('alphabetpronunciationn')">N n</button>

// This part can be reused
<script type="text/javascript">
  function play(audio_id){
    document.getElementById(audio_id).play();
  }
  function pause(audio_id){
    document.getElementById(audio_id).pause();
  }
</script>

// This part abstract the changing color animation into a class(attribute)
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".buttonchangingcolorblue").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
    }).mouseleave(function () {
$(this).removeClass("btn-primary");
    });
</script>
```

Coding really is of great fun! I love coding!